# Duplicate screen shot of first fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, screenshot

I have 2 fragments. First one is a checklist for live electrical work(safety check list)
[image]
, and a second fragmet which is also a checklist (non- live electrical work).
[image]
 What I'm doing is getting the user to take a screen shot of each fragment when they click "next". This is achieved by getting the user to click the "next" button which will take a screen shot of the current fragment, then loading the next fragment(goes from liveWorkFragment -> nonLiveWorkFragment). Same thing on the second fragment. The problem I am having is that the first fragment takes a screen shot no problem, it gets saved in the correct folder etc, but when I click next on the second fragment, it takes the screenshot, but when I go to look at the picture(fragment2 screenshot is called "SafetyCheckList2.png"), it's the same picture as fragment1. I have no idea why. 
This is the code to take a screen shot for fragment1:

```
View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.btnNext)
        {
            try
            {
                View u = view.findViewById(R.id.liveWorkLayout).getRootView();
                u.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                Bitmap b = u.getDrawingCache();

                //Setup the directory
                File mediaFolder = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null)+"/ArcFlash/CheckListMedia");
                if(!mediaFolder.exists())
                    mediaFolder.mkdirs();

                File fileName = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null)+"/ArcFlash/SafetyCheckList1.png");//CheckListMedia
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
                b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
                out.close();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Saved Picture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                        .setTitle("Continue")
                        .setMessage("You cannot return to this page after clicking next.")
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                                FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();

                                Fragment newFragment = new NonLiveWorkFragment();
                                transaction.replace(R.id.mainLayout, newFragment);
                                //transaction.addToBackStack("first");
                                transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                                transaction.commit();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // do nothing
                            }
                        })
                        .show();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                handler.Log(ex.getMessage(), "onClick (LiveWorkFragment.java)", context);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Code for fragment2:

```
View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.frag2Next)
        {
            try
            {
                View u = view.findViewById(R.id.nonLiveWorkLayout).getRootView();
                u.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                Bitmap b = u.getDrawingCache();

                File fileName = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null)+"/ArcFlash/SafetyCheckList2.png");
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
                b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
                out.close();

                Toast.makeText(context, "Saved Picture", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //Until I figure out how the heck to draw with a silly(being PG 13 here..) fragment,
                //I'm going to use an activity as the final page
                new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                        .setTitle("Continue")
                        .setMessage("You cannot return to this page after clicking next.")
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Intent signatures = new Intent();
                                signatures.setClass(getActivity(), Signature.class);
                                startActivity(signatures);
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // do nothing
                            }
                        })
                        .show();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                handler.Log(ex.getMessage(), "onClick Next (NonLiveWorkFragment.java)", context);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Couldn't load next page.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
};
```